# Which emoji plugin can be used in Angular with controller and services?

Tags: angularjs, emoji, angular-services, angular-controller

I want a emoji picker in side of a textarea. I have already tried emojioneArea but I have been stuck because in textarea I have ng-model and ng-change attribute but after implementing emojioneArea ng-change and ng-model and other attributes not working. Please suggest what can be done.

For ex:-
`<textarea id="message" ng-model="textmessage" placeholder="Type a message" ng-change="textarea-message"></textarea>`

And have initiated emojioneArea on id 'message'
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").emojioneArea();
});`

But ng-model is not getting updated. I'm using angular version 1.4.14

Comment: Hi, check out this link, it could help you so much : https://github.com/terranisu/angular-emoji-picker

Comment: @MrFlamme26 Thanks for suggesting, but I have already checked this out. For my use this is not suitable

Comment: depending on how it works, your emoji-picker may need to be added to the digest cycle with `$scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 0):

Try angular-emoji-filter-hd , it is a filter to replace emoji codes with emoticons
https://github.com/dbaq/angular-emoji-filter-hd